# Implementation of Mail::Send() in the custom Prestashop module for sending emails

Tags: php, email, prestashop-1.6

I tried to create a Prestashop module (called `TestOne`) for sending a mail to the customer every time new order is created. I am using `Mail::Send()` hooked within `actionValidateOrder` hook, however the whole module doesn't seem to work at all.

Please tell me what is wrong with my code - here is my `TestOne.php`:

```
    <?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class TestOne extends Module
{
    protected $config_form = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'TestOne';
        $this->tab = 'emailing';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Claire Penvenen';
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        /**
         * Set $this->bootstrap to true if your module is compliant with bootstrap (PrestaShop 1.6)
         */
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('TestOne');
        $this->description = $this->l('Testing TestOne module for sending an email to customers after they had made an order.');
    }

    /**
     * Don't forget to create update methods if needed:
     * http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Enabling+the+Auto-Update
     */
    public function install()
    {
        Configuration::updateValue('TESTONE_LIVE_MODE', false);

        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('header') &&
            $this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader') &&
            $this->registerHook('actionValidateOrder');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        Configuration::deleteByName('TESTONE_LIVE_MODE');

        return parent::uninstall();
    }

    /**
     * Load the configuration form
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        /**
         * If values have been submitted in the form, process.
         */
        if (((bool)Tools::isSubmit('submitTestOneModule')) == true) {
            $this->postProcess();
        }

        $this->context->smarty->assign('module_dir', $this->_path);

        $output = $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path.'views/templates/admin/configure.tpl');

        return $output.$this->renderForm();
    }

    /**
     * Create the form that will be displayed in the configuration of your module.
     */
    protected function renderForm()
    {
        $helper = new HelperForm();

        $helper->show_toolbar = false;
        $helper->table = $this->table;
        $helper->module = $this;
        $helper->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG', 0);

        $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
        $helper->submit_action = 'submitTestOneModule';
        $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false)
            .'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

        $helper->tpl_vars = array(
            'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFormValues(), /* Add values for your inputs */
            'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
            'id_language' => $this->context->language->id,
        );

        return $helper->generateForm(array($this->getConfigForm()));
    }

    /**
     * Create the structure of your form.
     */
    protected function getConfigForm()
    {
        return array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'label' => $this->l('Live mode'),
                        'name' => 'TESTONE_LIVE_MODE',
                        'is_bool' => true,
                        'desc' => $this->l('Use this module in live mode'),
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_on',
                                'value' => true,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_off',
                                'value' => false,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'col' => 3,
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'prefix' => '<i class="icon icon-envelope"></i>',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Enter a valid email address'),
                        'name' => 'TESTONE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL',
                        'label' => $this->l('Email'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'password',
                        'name' => 'TESTONE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD',
                        'label' => $this->l('Password'),
                    ),
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Set values for the inputs.
     */
    protected function getConfigFormValues()
    {
        return array(
            'TESTONE_LIVE_MODE' => Configuration::get('TESTONE_LIVE_MODE', true),
            'TESTONE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL' => Configuration::get('TESTONE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL', 'contact@prestashop.com'),
            'TESTONE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD' => Configuration::get('TESTONE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD', null),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Save form data.
     */
    protected function postProcess()
    {
        $form_values = $this->getConfigFormValues();

        foreach (array_keys($form_values) as $key) {
            Configuration::updateValue($key, Tools::getValue($key));
        }
    }

    /**
    * Add the CSS & JavaScript files you want to be loaded in the BO.
    */
    public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
    {
        if (Tools::getValue('module_name') == $this->name) {
            $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/back.js');
            $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/back.css');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the CSS & JavaScript files you want to be added on the FO.
     */
    public function hookHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/views/js/front.js');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/views/css/front.css');
    }


    public function hookActionValidateOrder($params)
    {
         $context = Context::getContext();
         $customer = $params['customer'];
         $customer_mail = $customer->email;
         Mail::Send(2,'test','Sending email test','Salut',$customer_mail,'My name');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- There is a `test` email template (test.) in `mails/iso_lang` folder where iso_lang is the iso code of language with ID 2??
- `$template_vars` param of Send function should be an array. You are sending 'Salut'. You can pass an empty array: `array()`.
- Other things you must check are related to email configuration in your shop. Try to test configuration at menu Advanced Parameters -> Email before continue.

Good luck.